# Как сохранить EventListener при обновлении страницы?

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

Есть кнопка, которая динамически создает кнопки, добавляет к существующему диву, вешает на них EventListener, и сохраняет все в localStorage.

При создании все работает как нужно, созданные кнопки реагируют на нажатие, но если обновить страницу, их прослушиватель пропадает.

Как можно сохранить на них прослушиватель после обновления страницы? 
Прописать onclick непосредственно в сам шаблон тега работает замечательно, но все же интересна альтернатива.

*Такая форма создания кнопки связана с тем, что в моем учебном проекте таким образом создается сразу древо тегов.

```html
<body>
  <button class="buttonCreate">Create</button>
  <div class="div"></div>

  <script>
    const div = document.querySelector(".div");
    const buttonCreate = document.querySelector(".buttonCreate");
    buttonCreate.addEventListener("click", createButton);

    function createButton() {
      div.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", "<button class='button'>button</button>"); //*
      div.querySelector(".button").addEventListener("click", () => alert("I`m button"));
      updateStorage();
    }

    function updateStorage() {
      let innerDiv = div.innerHTML;
      localStorage.setItem("div", JSON.stringify(innerDiv));
    };

    window.addEventListener("load", () => {
      div.innerHTML = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("div"));
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Альтернатива - вешать обработчик события на `<div class="div"></div>`. В `localStorage` можно сохранить только строки.